# I want some information about population inversion in graphene & build laser with this theory

Tags: laser, atomic-physics

I have read the paper

> Theoretical Study of Population Inversion in Graphene under Pulse Excitation. A. Satou, T. Otsuji and V. Ryzhii. [*Jpn. J. Appl. Phys.* **50** no. 7, pp. 070116-070116-4 (2011)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1143/JJAP.50.070116).

Can a graphene laser really be made?

Comment: Hi ehsan. Welcome to Physics.SE. Can you provide us a referenced link regarding the paper which you claim?

Answer (score 1):

The paper abstract indicates that a graphene laser could indeed (at least in principle) be made.

If you want to build a graphene laser yourself, I would first suggest you become proficient at fabricating graphene. The skills involved in that should help clarify what the issues would be in building such a laser.

And anyway, why do you want to build this? What's wrong with current lasers that graphene would solve?